# Sets Constructible Relative To A Unary Predicate

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

The class $L$ of constructible sets is defined by recursion using the operation def$(M)=\{x \subset M: x$ is definable over $(M, \in) \}$.  By adding a unary predicate, $P$, to our language, we can similarly define the class $L_{P}$ by using the operation def$_{P}(M)=\{x \subset M: x$ is definable over $(M,\in,P)\}$ instead of def$(M)$.

Assuming that $V \models$ ZFC (with Replacement and Comprehension schemas extended to included formulas that use $P$), is it true that $L_{P}$ is the smallest inner model of $V$ that satisfies these extended Replacement and Comprehension schemas?

Comment: This is theorem 13.22 (iii) in Jech's Set Theory book.

Comment: 13.22(iii) only applies if $A=\{x:P(x)\}$ is a set.  However, the construction of $L[A]$ makes sense even when $A$ is not a set.  I am interested in how Theorem 13.22(i),(iii) can be extended to the case where $P(x)$ is an arbitrary predicate (e.g. $P(x):= x$ is definable) that gets added to the existing language and model.